# Use immaximas to find the most common colour block in image?

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to apply a  64x64 sliding window across an image and output the most common colour in the that window. Would `immaximas` be what I am looking for? Or will this function give me the location of colour blocks?

Am example of my heuristic:

```
pkg load image;
pkg load signal;

i = imread('foo.jpg');

[r,c] = immaximas(i, 65);  % radius=65 ie a 65x65 kernel correct?
% I should now know the most common colour in 65x6 regions across the image right?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `immaximas` documentation.

> Find local spatial maximas.
>
> ...
>
> A local spatial maxima is defined as an image point with a value that
>   is larger than all neighbouring values in a square region of width
>   2*radius+1

so `immaximas` has nothing to do with finding the most common value.

The most common element in a list of numbers is called the mode. If you want to simply output the most common color at each point in the image you can use `nlfilter` from the image processing toolbox.

```
imode = nlfilter(i, [64 64], 'sliding', @mode);
```

If the image is 3 channel with type `uint8` you could encode the pixels into single value then find the mode. Also, it would be nice to ignore the implicit zero padding on the edges so we add 1 to the encoded value and find the mode of only non-zero values.

```
i = uint32(imread('peppers.png'));

% encode 3 channel image into single channel
ienc = 1+bitor(bitor(i(:,:,1), bitshift(i(:,:,2),8)), bitshift(i(:,:,3),16));

% find the mode
imode = nlfilter(ienc, [64 64], @(x) mode(x(x~=0)));

% decode single into 3 channel image
idec = zeros(size(i));
idec(:,:,1) = bitand(uint32(255), imode(:,:,1)-1);
idec(:,:,2) = bitshift(bitand(uint32(65280), imode(:,:,1)-1),-8);
idec(:,:,3) = bitshift(bitand(uint32(16711680), imode(:,:,1)-1),-16);
idec = uint8(idec);

imshow(uint8(idec));
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much your example is much appreciated - I'm learning Octave/Matlab. Thanks for taking the time to create this :)